# JavaScript: Convert string and concatenate it to dynamically create an object property reference

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6, eval

I'm creating an API where values are passed by the server via data attribute, so the JS can use to retrieve information... My JS makes a AJAX call and a JSON object is returned...

```
{
    "data": {
        "results": {
            "type": [
                {
                    "cars" : {
                        "brands": {
                            "ford" : {},
                            "honda" : {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In order to get the brand, I just type

```
let brand = data.result.type[0].cars.brands.ford
```

this way I can get the results I need, but I need to build this path dynamically, by joining 2 partials of the path. Like I said in the beginning of the question, some info are passed via data attribute and the info is `type[0].cars.brands.ford`... I need to join this to `data.result` in my code. I'm currently being able to get the desired result by using `eval()`, like so

```
entry.querySelectorAll('[data-brand]').forEach((e) =>
    let brand = eval('data.result.' + e.dataset.brand);
)
```

I know many of you will say that using `eval()` is bad and I'm very aware of it, but I just could not find a better way to make this to happen and there is another issue, when the brand, let's say, `nissan` is not on the JSON, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nissan' of undefined`... One could avoid this, by checking if the property exist, before continuing the code, but I don't know how to do this kind of test when `eval()` is involved.

So... basically, what I need, is a better way to dynamically build the property path, that can be tested to see if the property exist...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can use data.result['property_name']

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried that and did not work...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Jonasw enlighten me

Comment: The accepted answer by `Jonas w` worked perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const brand = e.dataset.brand.split(".").reduce((obj,id) => obj[id] || {}, data.results);
```

That doenst support brackets, so do:

```
type.0.whatever.keys
```

To return undefined for non existent keys (instead of an empty object):

```
const brand = e.dataset.brand.split(".").reduce((obj,id) => (obj || {} )[id], data.results);
```

Comment: thank you very very much... I did not know about the `reduce()`... I'll study more about it... It worked perfectly.. I just had to adjust the data attributes, to turn `type[0].cars.brands.ford` to `type.0.cars.brands.ford`

Comment: just one question... I'm stil getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sentra' of undefined` because the brand `nissan` was not set... so, basically this does not exist `type.0.cars.brands.nissan.sentra`... how do I stop the `reduce()` iteration, when a parent property does not exist? Would you know?

Comment: that works only when `nissan` is the last item... when the item is in the middle, it actually does not work well... in my example, the brand `nissan`comes before `sentra` so,  reduce does not exit when it is false, it keep going and searching for the result... that's when the error happen...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if data.result has the property first, and only then make your variable brand:

```
if(data.result.hasOwnProperty(e.dataset.brand)){
    let brand = data.result[e.dataset.brand];
}
```

Comment: That happens if `data.result` has none of the brands you are looping over.

Answer (score 0):

You can [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to find all keys, then iterate the keys using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and get the key value from the object:

```js
const obj = {"data":{"results":{"type":[{"cars":{"brands":{"ford":{"name":"ford"},"honda":{"name":"honda"}}}}]}}};

const brand = 'data.results.type[0].cars.brands.ford';

const getPathValue = (src, path) => path.match(/[^.\[\]]+/g)
    .reduce((p, k) => typeof p === 'object' ? p[k] : p, src);

const brandOBj = getPathValue(obj, brand);

console.log(brandOBj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check i.e. the [lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) method which allows you to access values of object using path.

If lodash is too big for you, just review their implementation.